# Lag on the desktop in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu

Installed by Xubuntu on 18.04.  When watching a video, sometimes a diagonal line appears, while scrolling a web page the same way. When you move the window on the desktop, lags are visible.
I made 2 videos, it can be seen there:

- https://my-files.ru/rc1knc
- https://my-files.ru/c14f3q

For the test, installed Mint 19.2 (based on Ubuntu 18.04), same problems. Mint 19.1 used to be - everything was fine.

Comment: What is your graphics driver?

Comment: You are having screen tearing. There is no univocal solution, and a solution will depend on your graphics card.

Comment: Intel G 2130 processor with integrated graphics. I do not know which driver is used, tell me how to look